# How to set time picker only set time from 8:30 am to 8:30 pm in bootstrap-datetimepicker.js?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="event_date">Start at</label>  
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input id="event_start_date" name="event_start_date" type="text"  placeholder="" class="form-control input-md event_date" required="">
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="event_date">End at</label>  
         <div class="col-md-8">
      <input id="event_end_date" name="event_end_date" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md event_date" required="">
      </div>
</div>`
```

JavaScript code:

```
$('#event_start_date').datetimepicker({
    minTime: "08:30:00"
});
```

I need to set timepicker start time as 8:30 AM to End time as 8:30 PM disable other time in time picker. How is possible please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i solved my problem with this code:

```
$('.event_date').datetimepicker({
        disabledTimeIntervals: [ [ moment().hour(0), moment().hour(8).minutes(30) ], [ moment().hour(20).minutes(30), moment().hour(24) ] ]
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

The docs are lacking here, but I found that the following items are the key.

Understand that the datetimepicker uses the moment.js library.

The disabledTimeIntervals takes an array of arrays that define a time range.

```
[ //outer array
  [ start_time, end_time],
  [ second_start_time, second_end_time]
]
```

The other key point is that when you define a moment, you need to include the hour and minute, leaving the defaults caused the filter to no work for me.

So if you wanted to define a shop that was open from 8:30 AM to 8:30 PM with a 30 minute, it would look as follows:

```
$('.event_date').datetimepicker({
    disabledTimeIntervals: [
      [moment().hour(0).minutes(0), moment().hour(8).minutes(30)],
      [moment().hour(20).minutes(30), moment().hour(24).minutes(0)]
   ]
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Haven't tried it myself but from the [docs](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disabledtimeintervals),

```
disabledTimeIntervals
4.14.40

Default: false
Disables time selection between the given moments
```

Comment: what's the value format to give in disableTimeIntervals

Comment: I Use disabledTimeIntervals: [{h: 0 }),{ h: 8 m: 30}, { h: 20 m:30 }, { h: 24 }] ,but i didn't get output

Comment: i Have got a error "option disabledTimeIntervals is not recognized!"

Comment: do you have http://momentjs.com/ ?  the variable has to be passed in that format.