# Bootstrap datetime picker does not validate hour & minute together when incrementing hours or minutes

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using the bootstrap [datetime picker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker).

I have set **enabledHours** between **8 am to 5 pm** and **stepping** to **30**. When i pick the current hour to be **5 pm** and increment the minute by **one step**,the result is a invalid date(5:30 pm). The expected result is not to allow incrementing the time, as it produces invalid date.

Same goes for hours also. E.g. if I pick the time as **4:30 pm** and try to increment the hour by **one step**, it produces **5:30 pm** which is not valid according to the enabled hours.

Any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31950948/495000

Turns out the trick is to use the disabledTimeIntervals option instead of EnabledHours.

Note that disabledTimeIntervals takes an array of arrays - representing a list of disabled ranges.

For example, I needed the following, which disables the times between 12:00 AM to 06:59 AM, and between 6:01 PM and 11:59 PM (technically 12:AM the next day the way it's written...). If you consider the inverse, this means I'm enabling from exactly 7:00 AM to exactly 6:00 PM.

```
.datetimepicker({
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    stepping: 15,
    disabledTimeIntervals: [
        [moment().hour(0).minutes(0), moment().hour(6).minutes(59)],
        [moment().hour(18).minutes(1), moment().hour(24).minutes(0)]
    ]
```